# How to enable Synchronizing the Index in if(EventDisabler())?

Tags: indexing, events, versions

I am adding data in event `item:versionAdded` and when adding new version then it is calling `item:versionAdded` event again. For solving this issue I am adding data under:

```
using (new EventDisabler())
{
--adding record--
}
```

However, it is adding data but when we are trying to fetch those data from Content Search API then it is not showing full data. Index is showing half data and when we publish data then it is showing whole data.

Here, I am asking how we can sync index with  EventDisabler()

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would use `item:versionAdding` event instead and not use `EventDisabler` at all. `item:versionAdding` event is called before `item:versionAdded` which you use now. It is used during adding version. All indexing would be then done properly as you are not disabling events.

Another option would be to run rebuild of master index once you are done with your processing.

Comment: Okay thank and I will try to use item:versionAdding instead of  item:versionAdded.

Comment: @Sonu use the voting mechanics, don't leave comments